# How to parse a javascript map into an array using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to parse a JS map, converting it into an array, with the following form:

```
[
  {
    name: "21 years old",
    totalUsers: 2,
  },
  ...
]
```

So, if for example I have this map:

```
const ages = {
  "21": 2,
  "18": 10,
}
```

The method "parseAges" has to return:

```
[
  {
    name: "21 years old",
    totalUsers: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "18 years old",
    totalUsers: 10,
  },
]
```

This is the way I am doing it using for...of (ES2017):

```
const ages = {
  "21": 2,
  "18": 10,
}

function parseAges() {
  const agesArr = [];

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(ages)) {
    agesArr.push({
      name: `${key} years old`,
      totalUsers: value
    })
  }

  return agesArr;
}

console.log(parseAges());
```

How can I do it without the for...of, in ES6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the way I am doing it using for...of (ES2017):

[for/of](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp#mark_forof) is part of ES6 ([ES2015](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)).

> How can I do it without the for...of, in ES6?

There was no particular syntax added in ES6, other than for/of, that would make this easier than using a newer or older syntax.

`Object.entries` is one alternative ([ES2017](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_2017.asp#mark_obj_entries)):

```
const list = Object.entries(ages).map(([age, users]) => ({
  name: `${age} years old`,
  totalUsers: users,
}));
```

`Object.keys` is another alternative (ES5/[ES2009](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es5.asp)):

```
const list = Object.keys(ages).map((age) => ({
  name: `${age} years old`,
  totalUsers: ages[age],
}));
```